# Facebook API (javascript) getting latest school education info

Tags: facebook-javascript-sdk

I'm very new to the facebook api for my website, and I am using the javascript sdk. I want to get the users latest school information, including school name, course and year of study. This is what I have so far but it breaks the login script and returns 'response.education.school is undefined'. I'm guessing I'll need some kind of for loop to go through the education array as most users have more than one school listed?

```
function login() {
    FB.login(function(response) {
        if(response.authResponse) {
            // connected
            FB.api('/me', function(response) {
                fbLogin(response.id, response.name, response.firstname, response.email, 
                        response.education.school.name, response.education.concentration.name, response.education.year.name);
            });
        } else {
            // cancelled
        }
    }, {scope: 'email, user_education_history, user_hometown'});
}
```

Comment: You are correct, its mostly array. Also make sure you have `user_education_history` permission and add `fields=education` along with `/me` to make sure you get the data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> response.education.school is undefined

This is because `responce.education` is an array of objects. This would be an example for me (actual information removed)

```
"education": [
    {
      "school": {
        "id": "", 
        "name": ""
      }, 
      "year": {
        "id": "", 
        "name": ""
      }, 
      "concentration": [
        {
          "id": "", 
          "name": ""
        }
      ], 
      "type": ""
    }, 
    ...
  ]
```

You need to iterate over it and process each educaional step e.g.

```
for(ed in response.education) {
   var school = response.education[ed].school;
   var schoolName = school.name;
   ...
}
```

And so on; you are currently passing an aobject structure to your `fbLogIn` that can't handle it. If you want the latest school education, you simply pick the one that has the most recent `year.name` value.